# IE8 hangs after pressing "print" button in browser print dialogue when rendering content assembed with javascript via an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, printing, internet-explorer-8

I've been working on this issue for a couple weeks now and have been unable to resolve it.  The problem is only reported by a small subset of IE8 users.  I have attempted to reproduce the problem by running a VM of windows xp, IE8 (same version users report), and synced browser security settings.  Despite this, I am unable to reproduce the problem for myself.  Reproducing it would be great, but ultimately all that matters is discovering the source of the problem.

The way the print function works is:

1. User presses a link on the page which triggers a javascript function.
2. The javascript performs some logic to get the content of a subsection of the page (based on which print link was clicked).
3. "exCanvas elements are set to display:none" because I found that they caused printing bugs.
   4.The element is printed using a slightly modified version of "Print Element" found here: http://projects.erikzaadi.com/jQueryPlugins/jQuery.printElement/

The user then is prompted with a print dialogue from IE.  When the user hits the "print" button IE hangs and can only be shutdown by ending the process.  If the user hits "cancel" IE does not hang and the user can continue about their business.

The user is able to use the default print functionality to print the entire page without trouble.  It is only when they used my javascript based print function that the browser hangs.

I've had the user run no-addon IE8, look in their windows event log, and disable some common problem features in IE8.

I'm really stumped as to where in the process this error may be occuring.  It seems to point to my javascript but it stumps me that the error occurs after the browser print dialogue print button is pressed.  I would expect the error to occur before the window.print() function is called on the focused iframe.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this bug has given me quite a bit of frustration.

Thanks.

EDIT----------------------------------------

I use the standard jquery print library above with a slightly custom _getMarkup function as seen below:

```
    function _getMarkup(element, opts) {
    var $element = $(element);
    var elementHtml = _getElementHTMLIncludingFormElements(element);

    var html = new Array();
    html.push('<html><head><title>' + opts["pageTitle"] + '</title>');
    if (opts["overrideElementCSS"]) {
        if (opts["overrideElementCSS"].length > 0) {
            for (var x = 0; x < opts["overrideElementCSS"].length; x++) {
                var current = opts["overrideElementCSS"][x];
                if (typeof (current) == 'string')
                    html.push('<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="' + current + '" >');
                else
                    html.push('<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="' + current["href"] + '" media="' + current["media"] + '" >');
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        $("link", document).filter(function () {
            return $(this).attr("rel").toLowerCase() == "stylesheet";
        }).each(function () {
            html.push('<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="' + $(this).attr("href") + '" media="' + $(this).attr('media') + '" >');
        });
    }
    //Ensure that relative links work
    html.push('<base href="' + _getBaseHref() + '" />');
    html.push(hieviews.getPrintCSS($("head").html()));
    html.push('</head><body style="' + opts["printBodyOptions"]["styleToAdd"] + '" class="' + opts["printBodyOptions"]["classNameToAdd"] + '">');

    var contentStr = $('<div></div>');
    $(contentStr).append($('#disclaimer').html());
    $(contentStr).append($('#nav').html());
    $(contentStr).append("<hr/><h3 class='table-header'>"+$(".title",$(element).parent().parent().children(":first")).text() +"</h3>");
    $(contentStr).append('<div>' + elementHtml + '</div>');

    var refTable = "";
    var total = $(".show-tooltip-text, .hidden_report",contentStr).each(function(index){
        if(index == 0){
            refTable += "<h3>Reference Table</h3><table class=\"dataTable\" id=\"cite\"><thead><tr><th>ref</th><th>Content</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
        }
        //if($(this).is(":hidden")){
        if($(this).css("display") != "block"){
            $(this).parent().append("<sup>*ref: #"+index+"</sup>");
            refTable += "<tr><td>"+index+"</td><td>"+$(this).html()+"</td></tr>";
        }
        if(index == total){
            refTable += "</tbody></table>";
        }
    }).length;
    $(contentStr).append(refTable);
    html.push($(contentStr).html());

    html.push('<script type="text/javascript">function printPage(){focus();window.print();' + ((!$.browser.opera && !opts["leaveOpen"] && opts["printMode"].toLowerCase() == 'popup') ? 'close();' : '') + '}<\/script>');
    html.push('</body></html>');
    return html.join('');
};
```

Comment: _"When the user hits the "print" button IE hangs and can only be shutdown by ending the process."_ - This really seems like an OS problem.  And if you cannot reproduce the issue or provide some code to review, there's little we can do other than give you troubleshooting pointers... then we're off-topic.

Comment: I was thinking something along those lines, but the fact that they can just go to my page and go "file -> print" and it works fine makes me think it has something to do with the javascript or my print process.


As far as code review goes, I use the library mentioned above.  I've also added the modifications I've made to the above post which are pretty minimal.
I'd also be welcome to any troubleshooting tips as I feel i've worn out my arsenal.

Comment: I had similar problems with a page where content was rendered in JS, and had CSS that hid most elements on the page. The page was basically a normal page with different CSS. The normal version worked ok, but once the new stylesheet was introduced, the problems started. So my best guess was that the heavy CSS hiding & heavy JS (map) rendering was too much for IE8 to handle.